# HighCharts - Highstock - Using showInNavigator and adding points after removing a series results in exception

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/za2576po/8/

I am working on a time series data chart that allows users to add or remove series from the chart as they want.

To allow the users to keep track of the trend in each series, I have set `showInNavigator` to `true`.

```
chart.addSeries({
  ...
  showInNavigator: 'true'
});
```

The chart is dynamic and new data comes in from our source every few seconds. I use `addPoint()` to add data to each series. I then redraw after all the points have been added to each series.

```
currentSeries.addPoint(datum, false, false, false);
...
chart.redraw();
```

If a series is removed from the chart dynamically using `remove()` and then new points are added, the chart throws an exception on 'redraw':

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/za2576po/8/

The provided sample can be used to reproduce this error by clicking each button below the graph, in order, from left to right:

1. Add another Series
2. Remove the first series
3. Add a point to each series

If you skip removing one or more series from the graph, you can add as many points as you like without an exception.

What do I need to do to avoid the exception?  I see that there can be multiples of the navigator series in the chart (See the console output as you click buttons in the sample.)

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/za2576po/8/

Comment: Hi Ross Graeber, This problem looks like a bug, so I reported it on Highcharts github. Here you can add your comments and watch the progress of the issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10193

Comment: Thank you for doing that for me.  I wasn't sure if this was a bug or operator error quite yet. Look like I can just `update()` the whole series as a workaround for now.